# Create overlay link

Tags: sxa

Iam using sitecore 9.1 and sxa 1.8, I created a rendering variant that has a "Link" component:

[image]

to open a content on an "Overlay".  Is there a way to pass the parameter "$id" from the rendering variant through the "Link" to a controller rendering displayed on the overlay??

Comment: Nothing like that out of the box.